# MultiValueDictKeyError at /accounts/signup/ 'password'

Tags: python, django

I am new in django python and I am getting this weird error during signup process.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

This is my code in views.py:

```
if request.method=='POST':
        #SignUp
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:

            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username = request.POST.get('username1'))
                return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error':'username is already taken'})

            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username1'], password=request.POST['password'])
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')

    else:
        #enter info
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
```

If i put `user= request.POST.get('username1')` I get the 'username already taken' message no matter what is my input.

my html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'signup' %}" class="form" autocomplete="off">

        {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form__group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username1" class="form__input" id="username1" autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form__group" autocomplete="off">
              <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" class="form__input" autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form__group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password1" class="form__input" />
          </div>

          <div class="form__group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password2" class="form__input" />
          </div>

          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="signup!"/>
      </form>
```

The error is:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /accounts/signup/
'password'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 2.2.9
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'password'
Exception Location: C:\Users\HP\Desktop\django\zakevenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 80
Python Executable:  C:\Users\HP\Desktop\django\zakevenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\django\\producthunt-project',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\django\\zakevenv\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\django\\zakevenv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\django\\zakevenv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\django\\zakevenv\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Anaconda3\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\django\\zakevenv',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\django\\zakevenv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 23 Jan 2020 15:20:06 +0000
```

I have spent hours and still I have no idea wheres I am doing wrong :( .
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `I get the 'username already taken' message no matter what is my input.` because it does not throw the exception. Look what the value of `user` is. | As to error of "password" - you have password1 and password2, not "password".

Comment: Oh yes. I totally missed that. I just thought theres some issue with POST request and missed a obvious one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if request.method=='POST':
        #SignUp
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:

            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username = request.POST.get('username1'))
                return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error':'username is already taken'})

            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username1'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')

    else:
        #enter info
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
```

**Error:** If you look your try block , you are trying to get a username then you are not doing anything by this username and then in render method you are sending an error message by assigning a information. So on the template file its showing the errors message since you send it as a default message.

Comment: Yes I did a bummer and wasted a lot of time. Thank you for saving my rest of the day.